# How does Keras work with sigmoid function and probabilities

Tags: python, keras, classification

I am trying to clasify a text by the main sentiment, positive or negative, with Keras. However, even though the code works, i don't completely understand two things.

1.How does the Dense layer with Sigmoid function work in order to clasify the text, considering that from what i understood, the "sigmoid" function returns a number between 0 and 1?
Does Keras by default consider 0 negative and 1 positive?

2.When using binary_crossentropy, what difference are we exactly calculating? I know that the differece is between the ground truth and our prediction. But which is which?

This is my code:

```
train_validation_split = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit([6, 4])
(train_data, validation_data), test_data = tfds.load(
    name="imdb_reviews",
    split=(train_validation_split, tfds.Split.TEST),
    as_supervised=True)

train_examples_batch, train_labels_batch = next(iter(train_data.batch(7)))
print(train_examples_batch)
print(train_labels_batch)
embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[],
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])  
model.fit(train_data.shuffle(10000).batch(512),
                    epochs=25,
                    validation_data=validation_data.batch(512),
                    verbose=1)

results = model.evaluate(test_data.batch(512), verbose=2)

for name, value in zip(model.metrics_names, results):
  print("%s: %.3f" % (name, value))
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: This is not so much related to programming as it is to statistics, so I voted for it to be moved to https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @nicolasGervais Okay, thank you